# faithful representation related to the center

Tags: representation-theory

> Let $H$ and $K$ be two finite groups, $G = H \times K$. $\phi$ is an irreducible representation of $H$, and $\psi$ is an irreducible representation of $K$ (both representations are finite-dimensional, over $\mathbb C$). Then $\phi \sharp \psi$ is faithful if and only if $(|Z(H)|,|Z(K)|) =1$.

Relative Definitions:
Tensor product of representations. Let $G_i$, $i=1,2$ be two finite groups, $(\rho_i, V_i)$ be a representation of $G_i$, $i=1,2$. Then the representation $(\rho_1 \otimes \rho_2, V_1 \otimes V_2)$ is defined to be $(\rho_1 \otimes \rho_2)(g) = \rho_1(g) \otimes \rho_2(g)$ for any $g \in G$.

Let $G = G_1 \times G_2$. $\rho_i$ is a representation of $G_i$, $i=1,2$. Let $p_i$ be the projection of $G$ to $G_i$, $i=1,2$.  Let $\rho_i'=\rho_i \circ p_i$, $i=1,2$. Then $\rho_1'$ and $\rho_2'$ are representations of $G$. Define $\rho_1 \sharp \rho_2 : = \rho_1' \otimes \rho_2'$.

MY PROBLEM: If I set $H$ to be a cyclic group of order $2$, and $K$ to be a cyclic group of order $3$. $\phi$ and $\psi$ are both $1$-dimensional representations sending everything to $1$. Then $\phi \sharp \psi$ still sends everything to $1$, so it is not faithful. Where is wrong? How can I give the proof?

Comment: Yeah, the question is flawed. You'd need $\phi$ and $\psi$ to be faithful as well. The central condition makes some sense (if $\phi \sharp \psi$ is also irreducible, then yes, then center of a group with a faithful irreducible representation is cyclic by Schur's lemma).

Comment: Yeah, if the problem is modified to replace all occurrences of "irreducible" with "faithful", then the problem is correct. If you replace both "irreducible" and "faithful" with "faithful and irreducible", then the problem is also correct.

Comment: @JackSchmidt Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).